# Magento REST API sample code 404s

Tags: php, .htaccess, rest, magento, oauth

When following the documentation from here
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html

The sample code below 404s when it tries to make the calls to the urls /oauth/initiate and 
/admin/oauth_authorize.

/api/rest works fine, as I have the current  rule in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
```

Is there other rules I am missing? It was my understanding the magento REST api should work out the box. Or could the issue be unrelated to url rewrites?

I have created the appropriate REST Roles and Attributes and placed the consumer key/secret inside the sample code also but no dice.

Just to clarify, a guest role works fine when hitting api/rest using a rest client or browser. However trying to set up authentication with the below sample code is causing me issues for the above reasons.

```
<?php
    /**
* Example of simple product POST using Admin account via Magento REST API. OAuth authorization is used
*/
$callbackUrl = "http://yourhost/oauth_admin.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://magentohost/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://magentohost/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://magentohost/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://magentohost/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'yourconsumerkey';
$consumerSecret = 'yourconsumersecret';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
        $productData = json_encode(array(
            'type_id'           => 'simple',
            'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
            'sku'               => 'simple' . uniqid(),
            'weight'            => 1,
            'status'            => 1,
            'visibility'        => 4,
            'name'              => 'Simple Product',
            'description'       => 'Simple Description',
            'short_description' => 'Simple Short Description',
            'price'             => 99.95,
            'tax_class_id'      => 0,
        ));
        $headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json');
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, $productData, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, $headers);
        print_r($oauthClient->getLastResponseInfo());
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e);
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this part `$callbackUrl = "http://yourhost/oauth_admin.php";` works? If if it is not working, fix this. Remember to replace value `http://yourhost/oauth_admin.php` with right value and try in your browser first.

Make sure that both `yourhost` and `magentohost` local or both remote server. For example if your `magentohost` is remote server and `yourhost` is local, redirection will fail and you will get 404 error.

Comment: Hi Krishna, 

I did create oauth_admin.php and can it it fine. The contents of the file itself is just writing a timestamp to a text file so I know its been hit.

It is never hit when running the sample code, but I can through my browswer and the server magento is installed on by running a wget both get positive results so it can be accessed.

Do you think it would still be the issue? What should the contents of that file be?

Thanks Krishna.

Comment: Make sure that both `yourhost` and `magentohost` local or both remote server. For example if your `magentohost` is remote server and `yourhost` is local, redirection will fail and you will get 404 error. p.s. I also edited my answer

Comment: Hi Krishna, 

Yes the hosts are both correct. The 404 is a magento 404, the actual magento application displaying the 404, not the web server.

This is why I thought perhaps it could be routing problem. For example if I removed

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

then hitting http://magentohost/api/rest would also 404.


Do we know what should be parsing /oauth/initiate? Is it also api.php like for api/rest or is it index.php?


Thanks for your comments Krishna.

Comment: Ahh... as you predited correctly, it must be issue with sever then. Can you try following `http://magentohost/customer/account/login/` and also try `http://magentohost/index.php/customer/account/login/`. Let me which one works and which has 404

Comment: Hi Krishna, 

Neither 404, /customer/account/login/ works, and index.php/customer/account/login/ redirects to /customer/account/login/.

Comment: Do we need to create oauth_admin.php and content of this file will be sample code as attached in question, Please conifrm